# SharePoint -copy library template when creating a new item

Tags: sharepoint

I have a document library with 4 content types, each having a default template. Users click on "New" and choose the content type for the new item.

I need WSS 3.0 to create a copy of that template (in the current folder) so that the users can edit it. I do not want WSS to open the template in a client application -I need it to leave the template right there.

How could I accomplish this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder what you mean by EDIT the template copy, you mean setting properties? cause otherwise you must open it in a client app.

Anyway, we did t before for a client, he needed a file naming convention feature, so we added a feature that replaced the New button options with our own option, that takes the user to our custom page, where he selects the content type and fill in appropriate metadata. When clicking OK, the template is copied to the folder, given name according to the convention and assigned metadata. After that we opened the file in a client app, but you don't have to do that. The whole thing involved

1. Feature XML files
2. Layouts custom page with code behind
3. Custom menu customizer code to hide the New button options

Hope it helps